# Existe uma maneira de usar acentos em strings em LUA?

Tags: lua, acentuação

Estou procurando uma maneira de usar acentos em strings na linguagem LUA. Eu já tentei fazer isso

```
texto='Pão,está,cabeçalho,'
```

porêm no motor que eu estou usando (o ROBLOX studio),o jogo só escreve até o trecho que tá com acento ou outro caráctere especial,e quando eu vou verificar o valor do `Text` (a variavel que faz escrever na tela seu valor),nos lugares das letras que tem acento tem uns sinais parecidos com esse: `<?>`

Alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: O problema maior é usar um editor de código no mesmo codepage de onde está a saída. Por exemplo. se salvou em UTF-8, só vai funcionar no Windows se der um `chcp 65001` antes. Experimente salvar em Win 1252 para ver, se for windows. É para funcionar normalmente. Verifique na opção "salvar como" do seu editor a opção encoding/codepage.

Comment: @Bacco Hmm... ainda não foi citado nenhum uso de arquivo na questão, mas se esse for o caso, talvez o script possa estar sendo codificado opostamente do renderizador de texto do Roblox.

Comment: Se ele está testando o script pra sair no console, depende do console. Se ele está vendo no Roblox mesmo, em teoria já deve vir configurado certo. O problema no caso que eu citei é se ele fez um script no Roblox e está testando em uma saída que não seja o Roblox mesmo. Só sabendo mais detalhes (um screenshot ou uma descrição melhor) do problema.

Comment: @TheProHands Ainda, pode ser o inverso, ele estar editando fora e tentando rodar o script no Roblox, vai saber. Só quis comentar com base no que dá pra supor, podem ser várias coisas diferentes.(e é claro, pode não ser nada disso kkk). O fato é que o encoding da entrada não bate com a saída, resta saber o motivo.

Comment: @Bacco Ou o caractere não  tem design também

Comment: @TheProHands Pode ser que falte na fonte usada, realmente. É que geralmente se o que aparece são `<?>`, é problema de decodificação de Unicode (ansi sendo tratado como unicode e dando erro), mas realmente uma fonte com caracteres faltando poderia deixar buracos no texto

Comment: @Bacco Correto. Na verdade nem sei muito sobre essas codificações ANSI, ASCII, ... não entendo porquê criaram :v.

Comment: Devem ser codificações padrões em alguns OS?

Comment: @TheProHands inicialmente as codificações foram feitas para ocupar 1 byte só. Mas isso não cobria diversas linguagens. Ai fizeram codificação com 2 bytes. Depois viram que precisava de mais e mais. Aí chegaram no Unicode, que pode ter varios bytes, mas ai ocupava muito espaço. Ai veio o encoding UTF pra tentar gastar bytes a mais só em caracteres menos usados. É muito detalhe pra comentar aqui, mas comentei só pra dar um pontapé inicial.

Comment: @Bacco Entendo. UTF-16 usa ao mínimo 2 bytes para representar um código de caractere. Tbm tem UTF-32, e deve que tem UTF-24.

Comment: @Bacco Deve ter até UTF-160.

Answer (score 1):

Isso depende de como a string é interpretada pelo renderizador. Por exemplo, talvez o renderizador trata cada byte da string como um código de caractere, ou em outros casos ele pode basear a leitura de códigos de caracteres entre bytes numa codificação.

Basicamente um valor do tipo *string* em Lua tem uma sequência de bytes, isso seria uma sequência de códigos de caracteres, e a linguagem não faz nada e nem se relaciona com esses códigos.

Dependendo de onde seu código é colado para ser executado, alguns caracteres podem ser codificados automaticamente. Por exemplo, como caracteres acentuados tem um código maior que 127, UTF-8, uma codificação geral de caracteres, adiciona 1 ou mais bytes para representá-lo.

Se você quer controlar a ação acima num caractere de string sem ter que modificar a codificação do seu código é possível gerá-lo pelo Lua usando seu código.

Se a versão for 5.3:

```
local texto = '\xXX';
```

Ou menor:

```
local texto = string.char(byte);
```

onde o componente XX/byte é o código do caractere, entre `0` e `255`. No primeiro exemplo o código fica no formato hexadecimal de 2 digitos.

Para conseguir o código de um caractere específico em bytes é preciso saber se ele tem ou não codificação, e qual. Normalmente seu código seria o primeiro byte, mas com codificações ele pode ser representado de outra forma, mas obviamente usando qualquer tamanho de bytes. Avisando que certas codificações permitem códigos maiores que 255.

Com as explicações mais acima sobre a codificação do código Lua à ser executado, o seu caractere especificado no próprio código pode ser codificado junto aos outros bytes do mesmo código. Se foi com UTF-8 é melhor usar uma biblioteca para manipulá-lo. Infelizmente está difícil de linkar as coisas no celular, por isso vou dar um exemplo de acordo com a biblioteca utf8 da versão 5.3:

```
local offsetI = utf8.offset(
    caractere, 1
);

local code = utf8.codepoint(caractere, offsetI);
```

Isso é uma aproximação. Agora você pode testar o renderizador de textos especificando cada caractere utilizando bytes. Se isso também não funcionar possa ser que ele usa outra codificação ou não tem jeito de renderizar esses caracteres ainda.

Comment: Desculpe,não sou muito bom em programação,não entendi nada,pode falar resumidamente?

Comment: Tentarei resumir: os caracteres especiais estão sendo representados ou codificados de maneira diferente do jeito que o renderizador interpreta-os, OU os caracteres especiais não tem seu design específico no próprio renderizador.

Comment: Nesse caso é preciso de mais alguns detalhes na tua pergunta.

Comment: Creio que não haja experts sobre Roblox aqui, mas o problema é provavelmente esse acima.

Answer (score -2):

-- https://gyazo.com/1c4ee2fc734a0d4aad22c7a2392da63a
Tipo assim?

```
Texto = "Pão,está,cabeçalho,"
script.Parent.Text = Texto
```

Se é isso que você queria...